# ASP.NET MVC Entity Framework query search

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, entity

How can I search data from single input like Hulk 2003 from SQL database when there are two columns in the database (`Movie_title` and `Release_Date`).

Just to be clear column `Movie_title` contains just the name of the movie and the release date of that movie is the column `Release_Date`.

I tried with

```
 public ActionResult Search(string search)
 {
     if (search == null)
     {
         return View("Index");
     }

     var Movie = db.Movies.Where(m => m.Movie_title .Contains(search) || 
                                      m.Release_date.Contains(search))
                          .ToList();

     return View(Movie);
}
```

Comment: Why would the release date include the movie title?

Comment: Why you need to search in release date for the movie title? This will not give you proper search result for sure....

Comment: i just name it movieTitle lets say that i named it search.... like this public ActionResult Search(string search)

Comment: your input is always like in this format => `Hulk 2003`, `Transformer 2007`, `Avenger 2012` means one space between both name and year

Comment: could u plz show your `Movie` entity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I manage to find solution, if you have better please post it ;)

```
  public ActionResult Search(string search)
    {
        int year = 0;
        string title = string.Empty;
        string yearparse = string.Empty;
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(search))
        {
            return View("Index");
        }

        string movieName = search;
        string movieYear = search;

        for (int i = 0; i < movieName.Length; i++)
        {
            if (char.IsLetter(movieName[i]))
            {
                title += movieName[i];
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < movieYear.Length; i++)
        {
            if (char.IsDigit(movieYear[i]))
            {
                yearparse += movieYear[i];
                year = int.Parse(yearparse);
            }
        }

        var Movies = db.Movies.Where(m => m.Movie_Title.Contains(title) && m.Release_date.Contains(year.ToString())).ToList();

        return View(Movies);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

try it :

```
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(search))
        {
    return View("Index");
         }

            string digit = new String(search.Where(Char.IsDigit).ToArray());
            string letter = new String(search.Where(Char.IsLetter).ToArray());
var Movies = db.Movies.Where(m => m.Movie_title.Contains(letter) || m.Release_date.Contains(digit)).ToList();//if Release_Date type is string 



   //for datetime type(just for year)

var Movies = db.Movies.Where(m => m.Movie_title.Contains(letter) || m.Release_date.Year==digit).ToList();

 }
```

Comment: Read question again :) and go to my project www.sedeljka.com and search movie hulk you will see 2 of them, but when you search it with hulk 2003 it return null